# How to update ERB template with inserted file in one Puppet run?

Tags: templates, dependencies, puppet, erb

I am attempting to build a file in Puppet 5 using an ERB template. This ERB file uses class variables in the normal fashion, but is also constructed by inserting another Puppet-managed local file. However, I find that whenever I update the inserted file, it takes *two* Puppet runs to update the ERB-generated file. I want the updating to happen in *one* Puppet run.

It is easiest to see this with an example:

```
# test/manifests/init.pp
class test {
  # This file will be inserted inside the next file:
  file { '/tmp/partial.txt':
    source => 'puppet:///modules/test/partial.txt',
    before => File['/tmp/layers.txt'],
  }

  $inserted_file = file('/tmp/partial.txt')
  # This file uses a template and has the above file inserted into it.
  file { '/tmp/layers.txt':
    content => template('test/layers.txt.erb')
  }
}
```

Here is the template file:

```
# test/templates/layers.txt.erb
This is a file
<%= @inserted_file %>
```

If I make a change to the file `test/files/partial.txt` it takes **two** Puppet runs for the change to propagate to `/tmp/layers.txt`. For operational reasons it is important that the update happen in only one Puppet run.

I have tried using various dependencies (`before`, `require`, etc.) and even Puppet stages, but everything I tried still requires two Puppet runs.

While it is possible to achieve the same result using an `exec` resource with `sed` (or something similar), I would rather use a "pure" Puppet approach. Is this possible?

Comment: You do know that you can concat two strings and pass them to `content`, right? That seems much easier than this approach.

Comment: The situation I described is a stripped-down version of the real situation. I do this to expose the essence of the issue. The real situation involves an arbitrary number of files, not just two.

Comment: The solution I settled on is to use Puppet 5's `each` array operator to construct a string containing the concatenation of all the files' contents (which _will_ be updated whenever any of the files is updated) and then to pass this string to the ERB file.

Comment: Well that's the first time you mentioned *multiple* files.  Are you trying to reinvent [the Concat module](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/concat)?

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned the multiple files from the beginning. I tried using the concat module but that has the same issue: it requires two Puppet runs. Combining the strings with the `each` operator is what worked.

Answer (score 3):

> I am attempting to build a file in Puppet 5 using an ERB template. This ERB file uses class variables in the normal fashion, but is also constructed by inserting another Puppet-managed local file.

A Puppet run proceeds in three main phases:

1. Fact collection
2. Catalog building
3. Catalog application

Puppet manifests are completely evaluated during the catalog building phase, including evaluating all templates and function calls.  Moreover, with a master / agent setup, catalog building happens on the master, so that's "the local system" during that phase.  All target system modifications happen in the catalog application phase.

Thus your

```
  $inserted_file = file('/tmp/partial.txt')
```

runs during catalog building, before `File[/tmp/partial.txt]` is applied.  Since you give an absolute path to the [`file()`](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.0/function.html#file) function, it attempts to use the version already present on the catalog-building system, which is not necessarily even the machine for which the manifest is being built.

It's unclear to me why you want to install and manage the partial result in addition to the full templated file, but if indeed you do, then it seems to me that the best way to do so would be to feed both from the same source instead of trying to feed one from the other.  To do this, you can make use of the `file` function's ability to load data from a file in the (any) module's `files/` directory, similar to how `File.source` can do.

For example,

```
# test/manifests/init.pp
class test {
  # Reads the contents of a module file:
  $inserted_file = file('test/tmp/partial.txt')

  file { '/tmp/partial.txt':
    content => $inserted_file,
    # resource relationship not necessary
  }

  file { '/tmp/layers.txt':
    # interpolates $inserted_file:
    content => template('test/layers.txt.erb')
  }
}
```

Note also that the comments in your example manifest are misleading.  Neither the file resource you present nor the contents of the file it manages are interpolated into your template, unless incidentally.  What is interpolated is the value of the `$inserted_file` variable of the class that evaluates the template.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation that clearly describes why my approach will not work. See my OP for an update on a different approach that worked for me.